# Finding the image of a point by analytic continuation of regular branch of $\sqrt{π^2 + \ln^2(z)}$ in $\mathbb{C}\backslash Γ$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation, branch-cuts

Denote $\varphi$ the regular branch of analytic function $\sqrt{π^2 + \ln^2(z)}$ in $\mathbb{C}\backslashΓ$ defined by $φ(1) = \pi$, and where $\Gamma$ is:

[image]

With only this information, I would like to find $\varphi(i)$.

But I have no idea how to start because this is, to me, a very hard topic on complex analysis and I'm a bit lost. Any advice what to do, how to understand the problem better or how to start?

Comment: No matter which branch of the $\ln$ you take, $\mathop {\lim }\nolimits_{z \to 0} \ln ^2 z =  + \infty $. The limit of $\varphi$ cannot be $1$ at $0$.

Comment: That is true, I edited my post!

Comment: If you specify $ - \frac{{7\pi }}{4} < \arg z < \frac{\pi }{4}$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \Gamma$, you can take $\log z = \log \left| z \right| + i\arg z$ and choose the brach of the square root that is positive on the positive real axis.

Comment: Thank you @Gary, but I find it hard to visualise what $\ln^2(z)$ would look like in this case, do you know ?

Comment: Could you explain to me how you found that interval for $\arg(z)$ by the way ?

Comment: There is a cut from $0$ along the ray $\arg z =\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: But aren't we supposed to avoid the part of $\Gamma$ between $-1$ and $\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}$?

Comment: Indeed, but it will be just a subdomain of what I described.

Comment: Oh okey thanks!

Comment: Okey I'm still stuck at the begining actually.. I don't see how to use your hint and avoid the part of $\Gamma$ we talked about. Do you think you could elaborate your idea @Gary?